# sorting tables with listview

Tags: c++, winapi, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm writing small program where I use `listView`, I want to sort data in table to the column which I clicked, and when I use `ListView_SortItems` to comparison function are transfer three parameters. Problem is that in function comp elements `lParam1` and `lParam2` always get value 0 and I compare the same cells in table.

When I use ListView_SortItems(hListView, 0, lParam); table is well sorted but only by first column.

How I can solve this problem?
My Code

```
int CALLBACK comp(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM lParam){

    NMLISTVIEW *pnmlv = (NMLISTVIEW*)lParam;

    TCHAR str[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR str2[MAX_PATH];

    ListView_GetItemText(pnmlv->hdr.hwndFrom, lParam1, pnmlv->iSubItem, str, MAX_PATH);
    ListView_GetItemText(pnmlv->hdr.hwndFrom, lParam2, pnmlv->iSubItem, str2, MAX_PATH);

    return (lstrcmp(str2, str));
}

case WM_NOTIFY:
if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->idFrom == 1000/*listViev ID*/) && (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == LVN_COLUMNCLICK)){
    ListView_SortItems(hListView, comp, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to make use of the third parameter, in your case named `lParam` - you can use this to pass info on which column should be the basis for the sorting.

Below is some code I found from an old RSS-reader project of mine. Hope it's of some use.

It looks like I'm just using it to hold -1,-2,-3 or 1,2,3. If it's negative I sort one way (asc/desc), if it's positive, I sort the other way. The number is simply the 1-based column number that had its header clicked.

The first two functions demonstrate determining which column was clicked and whether to sort in ascending or descending order, while the third function takes care of the little down or up arrows to indicate the column and direction of the sort.

```
/*
int CALLBACK CompareFunc(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2,
    LPARAM lParamSort);


The lParam1 parameter is the 32-bit value associated with the first item being compared;
and the lParam2 parameter is the value associated with the second item. These are the
values that were specified in the lParam member of the items' LV_ITEM structure when they
were inserted into the list. The lParamSort parameter is the same value passed to the
LVM_SORTITEMS message.

The comparison function must return a negative value if the first item should precede the
second, a positive value if the first item should follow the second, or zero if the two
items are equivalent.
*/
int CALLBACK myCompFunc(LPARAM lp1, LPARAM lp2, LPARAM sortParam)
{
    bool isAsc = (sortParam > 0);
    int column = abs(sortParam)-1;
    rssItem_t *item1, *item2;

    item1 = (rssItem_t*) lp1;
    item2 = (rssItem_t*) lp2;
    switch (column)
    {
        case 0:
            if (isAsc) return parseDateStr(item1->pubdate) - parseDateStr(item2->pubdate);
            else return parseDateStr(item2->pubdate) - parseDateStr(item1->pubdate);
            break;

        case 1:
            if (isAsc) return strcasecmp(item1->title.c_str(), item2->title.c_str());
            else return strcasecmp(item2->title.c_str(), item1->title.c_str());

        case 2:
            if (isAsc) return strcasecmp(item1->author.c_str(), item2->author.c_str());
            else return strcasecmp(item2->author.c_str(), item1->author.c_str());
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

// +----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// | -OnColumnClick()-
// | Called whenever the user clicks one of the list view's column headings.
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void OnColumnClick(LPNMLISTVIEW pLVInfo)
{
    static int nSortColumn = 0;
    static BOOL bSortAscending = TRUE;
    LPARAM lParamSort;

    // get new sort parameters
    if (pLVInfo->iSubItem == nSortColumn)
        bSortAscending = !bSortAscending;
    else
    {
        nSortColumn = pLVInfo->iSubItem;
        bSortAscending = TRUE;
    }

    // combine sort info into a single value we can send to our sort function
    lParamSort = 1 + nSortColumn;
    if (!bSortAscending)
        lParamSort = -lParamSort;

    // sort list
    ListView_SortItems(pLVInfo->hdr.hwndFrom, myCompFunc, lParamSort);
    setListViewSortIcon(pLVInfo->hdr.hwndFrom, nSortColumn, bSortAscending+1);
}

// state can be
// sortOrder - 0 neither, 1 ascending, 2 descending
void setListViewSortIcon(HWND listView, int col, int sortOrder)
{
    HWND headerWnd;
    const int bufLen = 256;
    char headerText[bufLen];
    HD_ITEM item;
    int numColumns, curCol;

    headerWnd = ListView_GetHeader(listView);
    numColumns = Header_GetItemCount(headerWnd);

    for (curCol=0; curCol<numColumns; curCol++)
    {
        item.mask = HDI_FORMAT | HDI_TEXT;
        item.pszText = headerText;
        item.cchTextMax = bufLen - 1;
        SendMessage(headerWnd, HDM_GETITEM, curCol, (LPARAM)&item);

        if ((sortOrder != 0) && (curCol==col))
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case 1:
                item.fmt &= !HDF_SORTUP;
                item.fmt |= HDF_SORTDOWN;
                break;
            case 2:
                item.fmt &= !HDF_SORTDOWN;
                item.fmt |= HDF_SORTUP;
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            item.fmt &= !HDF_SORTUP & !HDF_SORTDOWN;
        }
        item.fmt |= HDF_STRING;
        item.mask = HDI_FORMAT | HDI_TEXT;
        SendMessage(headerWnd, HDM_SETITEM, curCol, (LPARAM)&item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your function(onColumnCilck) and now when i click on column isn't any reaction(i use mesagebox to check this), also i deleted case WM_NOTIFY

Comment: In my code, it is actually fired in response to a `WM_NOTIFY` message. Inside the notify handler there's this: `if ( (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->idFrom == IDC_ITEM_LIST)&&(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == LVN_COLUMNCLICK) )
                OnColumnClick((LPNMLISTVIEW)lParam);
            return true;` - I also note that the style is `WC_LISTVIEW, WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_REPORT` (don't know if there's anything there that turns the arrow functionality on/off)

Comment: What library do I need for strcasecmp and what it is rssItem_t?

Comment: Well, you need `strings.h` for `strcasecmp`. (See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/strcasecmp.htm or http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp) As for rssItem_t - that's just a struct I defined for use in my application. If it helps you, the definition is as follows: `typedef struct
{
    string title;
    string description;
    string link;
    string author;
    string pubdate;
    string subject;
} rssItem_t;` (Define a struct that has meaning for your application - rssItem_t certainly will be of little to no use for you I imagine - `string` is std::string)

Comment: In code blocks after adding a library, program is working but when I click on column I have fatal error and in visual I even don't have this library.

What parameter should OnColumnClick take and what parseDateStr need?

Comment: I'm a bit busy just now unfortunately, so, here, I'll let you have a look for yourself. I've uploaded the entire project and its dependencies here: http://www.filedropper.com/rssreaderproj Let me know how you go. :)

Comment: Thanks for help, code was very helpful but I didn't solve problem, program is crashing when I do "item1->sth", also values lp1 and lp2 always are 0 so i will be compare the same items

Comment: You're welcome, a pleasure. :) If you have a look at about `line 200 of main.cpp`, you can see how I add items to the list-view. The important part is in the `SendMessage` call using `LVM_INSERTITEM`, I pass a pointer to the `rssItem_t` (type-cast to an `LPARAM`) structure that contains the data for that row. We have to hang on to it, so we can sort the lists. `Line 699 of main.cpp` shows me passing this pointer to the `addListViewItem` function. I've a little more time for the next hour or so. If you cant solve it yourself, I'd be prepared to take a look if you uploaded it.